# How to add colors to Excel output file in Powershell

Tags: excel, powershell, registry, ping

I have written a script to export specific registry keys and the sub keys inside it with the server ping response, but my scripts works as expected and I can able to export that to Excel as well.

But I need inputs or some help on how to add the colors to the Excel output column based on the value.

As Ex: in my script I will get ping response as true or false, for True I need to add green colour and for False I need to add Red color in my output, please help me to achieve this with my script.

**CODE**

```
## Get full list of servers
$Servers = GC -Path ".\Servers.txt"

## Loop through each server
$Result = foreach ($vm in $Servers) {

## Check the Ping reponse for each server
Write-Host "Pinging Server" $vm
$Ping = Test-Connection -Server $vm -Quiet -Verbose 
    if ($Ping){Write-host "Server" $vm "is Online" -BackgroundColor Green}
    else{Write-host "Unable to ping Server" $vm -BackgroundColor Red}

## Check the Network Share path Accessibility
Write-Host "Checking Share Path on" $vm
$SharePath = Test-Path "\\$vm\E$" -Verbose
    if ($SharePath){Write-host "Server" $vm "Share Path is Accessible" -BackgroundColor Green}
    else{Write-host "Server" $vm "Share path access failed" -BackgroundColor Red}

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $vm {

## Get ChildItems under HKLM TCPIP Parameter Interface
Get-ChildItem -Path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces' | ForEach-Object {
          Get-ItemProperty -Path $_.PSPath | Where-Object { $_.PsObject.Properties.Name -like 'Dhcp*' }
 } | Select-Object -Property @{Name = 'ComputerName'; Expression = {$env:COMPUTERNAME+"."+$env:USERDNSDOMAIN}},
                             @{Name = 'Ping_Response'; Expression = {if($using:Ping) {'Pinging'} else {'Unable to ping'}}}, 
                             @{Name = 'Share_Path_Access'; Expression = {if($using:SharePath) {'Accessible'} else {'Not Accessible'}}},
              DhcpIPAddress, @{Name = 'DhcpNameServer'; Expression = {$_.DhcpNameServer -split ' ' -join '; '}},
              DhcpServer,    @{Name = 'DhcpDefaultGateway'; Expression = {$_.DhcpDefaultGateway -join '; '}}
}}
$Result | Select-Object * -Exclude PS*, RunspaceId | Export-Excel -Path "$PSScriptRoot\TCPIP_Interface_Details.xlsx" -AutoSize -BoldTopRow -FreezeTopRow -TitleBold -WorksheetName TCPIP_Interface_Details
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`New-ConditionalText`](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel/blob/master/Examples/ConditionalFormatting/ConditionalText.ps1) cmdlet to highlight cells containing the specified `-Text` with the color of our choice. The cmdlet can also take RGB colors. I encourage you to read the documentation on it, there are also many examples:

```
Get-Help New-ConditionalText
```

Since I don't have access to your `$result` object I can only give you an example of how you can do it using a simple example:

```
$result = 0..10 | ForEach-Object {
    [pscustomobject]@{
        ComputerName  = 'Host' + $_
        Ping_Response = ('Not Responding', 'Pinging')[($_ % 2)]
    }
}

function RGB ($red, $green, $blue ){
    return [System.Double]($red + $green * 256 + $blue * 256 * 256)
}

$fontGreen = RGB 0 97 0
$backGreen = RGB 198 239 206
$condProps = @{
    Text = 'Pinging'
    ConditionalTextColor = $fontGreen
    BackgroundColor = $backGreen
}
$conditionalTrue  = New-ConditionalText @condProps
$conditionalFalse = New-ConditionalText -Text 'Not Responding'

$props = @{
    AutoSize        = $true
    InputObject     = $result
    Path            = 'test.xlsx' # => Use your absolute Path here!
    TableName       = 'myTable'
    TableStyle      = 'Medium11'
    WorksheetName   = 'myWorkSheetName'
    ConditionalText = $conditionalTrue, $conditionalFalse
}

Export-Excel @props
```

The end result should look something like this (unfortunately Google Sheets doesn't do it justice):

[image]