# Unable to export the data to CSV or Excel

Tags: powershell, dns, ping, nslookup

I have written a script to check the nslookup for each server and export the details to Excel, but my script is looking but I am not able to export the output when I export I a getting empty data.

Please help me to export the data to Excel

**CODE**

```
## Loop through each server for Nslookup
foreach ($Server in $Servers)
{
    $Addresses = $null
    try {
        $Addresses = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses("$Server").IPAddressToString
    }
    catch { 
        $Addresses = "Server IP cannot resolve"
    }
    foreach($Address in $addresses) {
        #write-host $Server, $Address
         $Server_Name = $Server
         $IP_Address = $Address                 
    } 
  } 
$result | Export-Excel -Path $FileName -AutoSize -BoldTopRow -FreezeTopRow -TitleBold -WorksheetName Server_Nslookup_Details
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your inner `foreach` loop is producing no output, just assigning values to the 2 variables (`$Server_Name` and `$IP_Address`):

```
foreach($Address in $addresses) {
    $Server_Name = $Server
    $IP_Address = $Address
}
```

You likely meant to construct a [new object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-pscustomobject?view=powershell-7.2) instead:

```
$result = foreach($Server in $Servers) {
    $addresses = try {
        [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses($Server).IPAddressToString
    }
    catch {
        "Server IP cannot resolve"
    }
    foreach($address in $addresses) {
        [pscustomobject]@{
            Server    = $Server
            IPAddress = $address
        }
    }
}

$result | Export-Excel ....
```

Comment: Can you help me like how to add color to specific text in the Excel output file

Comment: @chandu please ask a new question for that, adding what have you tried and your expected result

Comment: i tried something nothing is working out, I already created a new discussion https://superuser.com/questions/1714686/how-to-add-color-to-specific-text-in-excel-output-file-using-powershell

Comment: @chandu im guessing youre looking for something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71721884/15339544 (if so, I recommend you to move your question to SO instead of SuperUser)