# importexcel conditional formatting: How to apply color to entire row

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to color rows depending on the value of a cell.
eg: if A2 = 1, then color the entire row red ;  if A3 = 10 then color entire row orange, etc.
So far I've only managed to get the cell containing the value I'm checking the value of, to have the color applied. ie if A2 =1 then A2 is red but not the entire A row.
This what I'm doing:

```
        $Params = @{
        WorkSheet = $xl.Workbook.Worksheets[1]
        Range = "A2:A500"
        BackgroundColor = "Red"
        RuleType = 'Equal'
        ConditionValue = "1"
    }
    Add-ConditionalFormatting @Params
```

I'm using [importexcel](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel)

Any help & suggestions gratefully received!

Comment: I think if you just dont include the `Range` parameter it will be applied to all the column, here is an example using `New-ConditionalText` https://stackoverflow.com/a/71721884/15339544

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't solve the issue. I've been trying to follow examples in here:https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel/tree/master/Examples but not figured it out yet