# Powershell Export-Excel removes decimals

Tags: windows, powershell

I am trying to extract cpu/ram values and be able to extract them to excel. even if the value (%) is greater than 80, the excel appears red.

The first problem is that Excel appears in values without decimals. although the script outputs values on the screen in decimals ex: 27.54

| Server name | CPU % | Memory % |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ATONSP1 | 60,5 | 77,65 |
| ATONSP2 | 20,75 | 63,54 |
| ATONSQL1 | 25,8 | 71,15 |

How do I get the resulting Excel to come out with decimals?

```
$Servers = Get-Content "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\serversTest.txt"
$Array = @()
 
ForEach ($Server in $Servers) {
    $Check = $Processor = $ComputerMemory = $RoundMemory = $Object = $null
    $Server = $Server.trim()
 
    Try {
        # Processor utilization
        $Processor = (Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $Server -Class win32_processor -ErrorAction Stop | Measure-Object -Property LoadPercentage -Average | Select-Object Average).Average
 
        # Memory utilization
        $ComputerMemory = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $Server -Class win32_operatingsystem -ErrorAction Stop
        $Memory = ((($ComputerMemory.TotalVisibleMemorySize - $ComputerMemory.FreePhysicalMemory)*100)/ $ComputerMemory.TotalVisibleMemorySize)
        $RoundMemory = [math]::Round($Memory, 2)
         
        # Creating custom object
        $Object = New-Object PSCustomObject
        $Object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Server name" -Value $Server
        $Object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "CPU %" -Value $Processor
        $Object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Memory %" -Value $RoundMemory
 
        $Object
        $Array += $Object
    }
    Catch {
        Write-Host "No se encuentra el servidor ($Server): "$_.Exception.Message
        Continue
    }
}
 
#Final results
If ($Array) { 
  #  $Array | Out-GridView -Title "CPU and Memory"
   # $Array | Export-Csv -Path "$env:USERPROFILE\results.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Force
    

   $array | Export-Excel -Path C:\users\4749\Informe.xlsx 
}
```

In Excel:

| Server name | CPU % | Memory % |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ATONSP1 | 605 | 7765 |
| ATONSP2 | 2075 | 6354 |
| ATONSQL1 | 258 | 7115 |

How do I get the resulting Excel to come out with decimals?

I would like an excel document that highlights the value if it is greater than 80

Comment: What's your ImportExcel Module version ? `Get-Module ImportExcel`

Comment: Meanwhile better coders than me find a solution, have a couple suggestions: 1. when you plan to modify a collection, like adding or removing items, do not use Array but `[System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]::New()`: this will improve its efficiency, plus you can add elements with simply `$ListName.Add($ItemToAdd)`.      2:  instead of creating the Object then adding properties, create it with its properties: `$Object=[pscustomobject]@{ 'Server Name' = $Server; 'CPU %' = $Processor; 'Memory %' = $RoundMemory   }`

Comment: You could go straight to the source with a question. https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel/issues

Comment: PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-Module ImportExcel

ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands                                                              
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------                                                              
Script     5.0.1      importexcel                         {Add-ConditionalFormatting, Add-WorkSheet, BarChart, Close-ExcelPackage...}

Comment: You're using a very old version of the module, in latest version you shouldn't be facing this issue. Close your powershell and start a new one and run `Update-Module ImportExcel` then try your code again, decimal should be fine after. As for highlighting of cell if above 80, you can use `New-ConditionalText`, see this answer as example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71719264/how-to-add-colors-to-excel-output-file-in-powershell/71721884#71721884

Comment: This Solution: update new version Import-Excel. Thanks